# How to change HTML select option items using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, html-select

I have a form and user will select city. When the user selects the city, the town list will change to bring it to the cities of the towns.

I want to delete the towns of non-selected cities.

I have a code but it does not work :

```
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="city">City :</label>
            <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control" required onchange="townChange()">
                @foreach (var cityItem in Model.cityList)
                {
                    <option value="@cityItem.Id">@cityItem.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="town">Town :</label>
            <select name="town" id="town" class="form-control" required>
                @foreach (var townItem in Model.townList)
                {
                    <option value="@townItem.Id" accesskey="@townItem.CityId">@townItem.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>

function townChange()
{
    var cityId = document.getElementById("city").value;
    var townlist = document.getElementById("town");
    for (var i = 0; i < townlist.length; i++) {
        if (townlist.options[i].accessKey == cityId)
            townlist.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not try to loop ***townlist***-variable since it only contains the town select-element. Try loopin through the townlist.options instead.

Comment: But this is the example of deletion https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_remove.asp. @Esko

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML select dropdownlist with javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647358/html-select-dropdownlist-with-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0):

You tagged jquery but you are not actually using jquery in your code.

If you are willing to try jquery, something like this should work, but I am unable to test at the moment:

```js
$('#town option').each(function () {
  if ($(this).prop('accesskey') !== cityId) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your loop with this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < townlist.length; i++) { if (townlist.options[i].accesskey == cityId) townlist.remove(i); }
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("town")` you were looping with this which is the element itself u need to loop through the `options` of the select element.
Try this function

```
function townChange()
{
    var cityId = document.getElementById("city").value;
    var townlist = document.getElementById("town");
    var options = townlist.options;
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (townlist.options[i].accessKey != cityId)
        {
            townlist.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This method works a bit, but does not delete all of the things that need to be deleted. @Riaz

Comment: @D.Dirik i deleted all options which dosent matches the townlist.accessKey  with the selected cityId  . is the logic correct ?

Comment: since u said "I want to delete the towns of non-selected cities" ? so i did that , i gusess the logic is correct.

Comment: The logic is correct but unfortunately it does not work exactly. @Riaz-laskar

Comment: @D.Dirik ok so whats the issue can u elaborate a little plz

Comment: Thanks, I handled :)